# Stripe Webhook 404 error when using Parse Cloud Code and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to test my Parse Cloud Code using Stripe's test webhooks function.

My deployed Cloud Code shows up on my Parse dashboard, and I've pushed my app to heroku, so I have a live endpoint to for Stripe to send their requests to.

I'm following the tutorial here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/

I set up the endpoint in my server.js file via: `app.use('/webhooks', ParseCloud.app);`

Inside `/Parse/cloud/main.js`, I have the function:

```
var ParseCloud = require('parse-cloud-express'),
Parse = ParseCloud.Parse;

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

For my stripe webhook, the test request is sent to the following endpoint via a POST request:

```
http://app-name.herokuapp.com/webhooks/function_hello
```

The response I get is a 404 not found.

I have embedded the Parse app inside my Node.js app using Parse new, so I have a folder structure like this:

```
.app_folder
/.app #Holds all static files
/.bin
/.node_modules
...
/.Parse #Holds cloud code, and parse config folders.
```